# Analytic characteristic function convergence

Tags: weak-convergence, characteristic-functions, analyticity

This feels a bit silly, but I can't seem to find a nice reference. I have a weakly converging sequence of random variables $X_n \Rightarrow X$. The characteristic functions $\phi_n(s) := \mathbb{E}[e^{isX_n}]$ are analytic in a fixed complex neighborhood $N$ of $0$ and converge uniformly on compact subsets of $N$ to an analytic function $\psi(s)$ on $N$.

By Levy continuity, $\phi(s) := \mathbb{E}[e^{isX}] = \psi(s)$ for $\mathbb{R} \cap N$. I want to conclude that
$$\psi(s) = \mathbb{E}[e^{isX}] \qquad\text{for all }s \in N.$$
Can I do so? Moreover, is it written down somewhere? It just seems like such a natural thing to want, but none of the sources I've looked at (e.g. Billingsley) talk about it, so I'm probably looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from Lukacs, *Characteristic Functions*, 2nd Edition (1970), Thm. 7.1.1 and the discussion preceding it (p. 191-193). As you would expect, Lukacs shows that if a characteristic function agrees with an analytic function in a neighborhood of the origin, then $\mathbb{E}[e^{izX}]$ agrees with that analytic function in a strip $-\alpha < \mathrm{Im}(z) < \beta$, which is exactly my desired conclusion.